# How to get specific div through this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I build a method that allow me to return the clicked element by the user, something like this:

```
$('#button2').on('mouseover', function()
{
   console.log(this);
}
```

this return:

```
<tr id="res-7" class="entry border-bottom" rel="popover" data-original-title="" title="">
    <td style="padding-left: 10px">
        <div class="name"><strong>Test</strong></div>
        <div class="description">Foo</div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

essentially my target is get the content of div `name` and div `description`, someone could explain how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You say click but you used mouseover. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjs2v2fc/3/)

```
$(document).on("mouseover","tr", function(){

var name = $(this).find(".name").text();
var description = $(this).find(".description").text();
 console.log("Name: "+name+"\nDecsription: "+description);

})
```

Don't forget ID of each element must be unique so  your code is not correct because "#button2" must be unique, so this is always #button2 in your function.

Note the difference between text() and html(). I used .text() to get just the text without "strong" code. If you need it use html().

Answer (score 1):

You could use innerHTML

```
$(this).find('name').innerHTML; //returns "test"
$(this).find('description').innerHTML; //returns "foo"
```

This will find the class within the current element, and return the values you need.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an `id` on your element, accessing the `name` and `description` attributes is easy:

```
$('#button2').on('mouseover', function() {
   var $res7 = $('#res-7');

   // Access the two divs
   var name = $res7.find('.name').text(); // or .html()
   var description = $res7.find('.description').text(); // or .html()

   // Print them out
   console.log(name);
   console.log(description);
});
```

Of course, this block of code should be inside a jQuery `ready` event handler.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure there is a cleaner way, but this should get you what you want.

```
$('#button2').on('mouseover', function()
{
   console.log($(this).find(".name").html());
   console.log($(this).find(".description")).html());
}
```